# Harry Potter fanfiction where Harry, Hermione, Ron, Fred and George form Marauders new generation

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Harry, Hermione, Ron, Fred and George form a new generation of Marauders. They even make their own common room beside the Gryffindor common room. In the story, Harry makes teddy bears in McGonagall's class and sells them for 1 sickle each.

Comment: Do you read your fanfiction off of a particular site? Do you know approximately what year the story was set in? Were the teddy bears a frequent element, or just the chapter you read?

Comment: No it was just mentioned in 2 or 3 chapters

Comment: Do you know if it was on Fanfiction.net? ArchiveOfOurOwn? Another site?

Comment: Fanfiction.net.